# Mouse options not working in Vim on Git-Bash Windows

Tags: git, bash, vim

I have `set mouse=a` in my user `.vimrc`, which is where `$MYVIMRC` leads to, and editing this `.vimrc` does reflect my vim client (for example changing the `colorscheme` works).
However, the mouse options are not working.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html
In the above link I found some information about 
which terminals it works in:

> Enable the use of the mouse.  Only works for certain terminals
>       (xterm, MS-DOS, Win32 |win32-mouse|, QNX pterm, *BSD console with
>       sysmouse and Linux console with gpm).

So my question is, using Git-Bash on Windows, am I not able to use mouse controls? Or is there an issue with my `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) is [based on mingw64 form the msys2 project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309).
See more at "[How are msys, msys2, and msysgit related to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25019057/6309)"

[`vim` was reported not fully compatible with it before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10907250/6309).

You can either set options like:

```
set nocompatible
set backspace=2
```

Or make sure to use [gvim](https://gvim.en.softonic.com/) instead of vim.

Answer (score 1):

git for windows uses 2 terminals. One is the standard Windows console, another is mintty.

As far as I can see for git version 2.11.0.rc1/Windows 10, mouse works in mintty (I tried selection and scrolling), but not in windows console.